# How to display half of a character(html entity) using css (and if required jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the html entity (code) & #9679; which is a dark filled circle(●).
I want to display the first or the second half of the image(filled semi circle).

I could use image of a filled half circle to achieve this but I want to use html entity since that reduces page load time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the easiest method would be to just use the the Unicode 'RIGHT HALF BLACK CIRCLE' character, HTML entity `&#9687;`.

> ◗

See  Wikipedia: *[Geometric Shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes)*

---

**Update:** For a more general solution, you could use something like this:

```
<span class="clip">
    <span class="l-half">&#9673;</span>
</span>

.clip {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.l-half {
    font-size: 72px;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/3SH9L/)